# Opening MSWord from MSAccess using VBA - 429 Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime, activex

I have a really simple bit of code that I'm trying to in Ms Access 2010.  I want a control on a form to open a word document.  I've tried several things but the simplest piece of code I've cobbled together is as follows:

```
Private Sub CmdWord_Click()

Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    With wordApp
        .Visible = True
        Set wordDoc = .Documents.Add

    End With

End Sub
```

This compiles but when I run it without Word being open I get "run time 429 error: activex component can't create object.

With Word open I get a new document opening.

I have tried updating references to ADO 6.0 to no avail.  I'm new to VBA so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally open a file with the registered application with FollowHyperlink.

```
 FollowHyperlink "z:\docs\word.docx"
```

Otherwise, you can use CreateObject when Word is not running.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oWord = GetObject(,"Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

oWord.Visible = True
```

Comment: Thanks Remou.  The FollowHyperlink was sufficient.